# How to make bar disappear after clicking "I agree" using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKuZB.png)does anyone know how to get that bar to disappear after clicking "I agree"? I have been looking on bootstrap but couldnt find the solution. Please help. Below is my code:

```
<div id="cookie-message" class="cookie-message notification center-horizontal bottom static enable"> 
            <div class="strip color-ash" >
              <span class="show-tablet">We use cookies to deliver our services.</span>
              By using our website, you agree to the use of cookies as described in our&nbsp;
              <a class="color-oil" href="/assets/static/downloads/privacy-policy.pdf" target="_blank">Privacy&nbsp;Policy</a>&nbsp;—&nbsp; &nbsp;<a tabindex="0" href="#" class="cm-close color-deepblue">I&nbsp;Agree</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: javascript would go a long way ...

Comment: add event listener which is changes style to `display:none` after click event.

Comment: toggle a class on the input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target link with coresponding classes `.cm-close.color-deepblue`; Add event listener to it; And on click make `parentNode`(div id="cookie-message") display none.

```html
<div id="cookie-message" class="cookie-message notification center-horizontal bottom static enable">
  <div class="strip color-ash">
    <span class="show-tablet">We use cookies to deliver our services.</span> By using our website, you agree to the use of cookies as described in our&nbsp;
    <a class="color-oil" href="/assets/static/downloads/privacy-policy.pdf" target="_blank">Privacy&nbsp;Policy</a>&nbsp;—&nbsp; &nbsp;<a tabindex="0" href="#" class="cm-close color-deepblue">I&nbsp;Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  document.querySelector('.cm-close.color-deepblue').addEventListener('click', (event) => event.target.parentNode.style = "display:none")
</script>
```

Symplified version with bar would be:

```html
<div id="bar">

  <div id="cookie-message">
    <div>
      By using our website, you agree to the use of cookies as described in our&nbsp;
      <a href="#">Privacy&nbsp;Policy</a>&nbsp;—&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="link">I&nbsp;Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
  document.querySelector('.link').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('#bar').style = "display:none")
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I see that this works when I run the code snippet. I am new to jquery so I would  like to know how i would implement this in my code.

Comment: @kenny335 This is with the code that you provided.
P.S. It's vanilla JS, not jquery.

Comment: @kenny335 just put this JS code(as in snippet above) in `<script>` tag after that div you trying to hide.

Comment: Good news!It worked! Thanks so much! I just have one more question. If you look at the my post, I added a picture of the bar I am trying to hide. I was able to hide the text when I click "I Agree". But is there any way to hide the whole bar itself when I click it?

Comment: @kenny335 It's simple. You need to target not parent but the bar itself. By id or class. `document.querySelector('.cm-close.color-deepblue').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector(ID or CLASS).style = "display:none")`

Comment: @kenny335 this are relevant links https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @kenny335 I added a simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap, try this with jQuery:

```
$('.color-oil').on('click', function() {
    $('#cookie-message').hide()
})
```

1. You're adding a click event listener to the link
2. When that click happen, we get the div and call the hide method.

Let me know if it works for you.